# Strange behaviour of IPython

Tags: python, ipython

In IPython I type the following program

```
def foo():
   ...:     return 2
   ...: print(foo())
```

I would expect to see the output '2'.I don't see anything of that sort?I can't seem to figure out why?

Comment: add a newline after the `return`

Comment: This example works for me and prints 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IPython expects another a newline after your `return` statement, so just hit the enter key when you're done defining `foo`. It won't finish letting you define `foo` until you've closed the last level of indentation.

You may also notice that when you add the newline IPython immediately executes the `print` function in the code block you've just defined.

```
In [1]: def foo():
   ...:     return 2
   ...: print(foo())
   ...: 
2

In [2]:
```

If you want to avoid that side effect define your `foo` function, add a newline after your `return` to close off the function definition, and then call `print` separately like so:

```
In [1]: def foo():
   ...:     return 2
   ...: 

In [2]: print(foo())
2

In [3]:
```

Even if you do choose to write your code block the way you've written it now `foo` will still be defined as expected since your call to `print` is outside the scope of `foo`. Any subsequent calls to `foo` should work as expected.

```
In [1]: def foo():
   ...:     return 2
   ...: print(foo())
   ...: 
2

In [2]: foo??
Type:       function
String Form:<function foo at 0x246cde8>
File:       /home/siemenr/<ipython-input-1-f97d0fe9d8f9>
Definition: foo()
Source:
def foo():
    return 2

In [3]: print(foo())
2

In [4]:
```